# Speed-critical section in gcc?

Tags: compiler-optimization, avr-gcc

I'm already using `-O3`, so I don't think I can do much better in general, but the generated assembly is still a tight fit for the timing requirements.  Is there a way to, for example, tell `avr-gcc` to keep non-speed-critical code out of a speed-critical section?

```
if (READY)
{
    ACKNOWLEDGE();

    SETUP_PART1();
    SETUP_PART2();

    //start speed-critical section
    SYNC_TO_TIMER();
    MINIMAL_SPEED_CRITICAL_CODE();
    //end speed-critical section

    CLEANUP();
}
```

A tedious reading of the `-O3`-optimized assembly listing (`.lss` file) shows that `SETUP_PART2();` has been reordered to come between `SYNC_TO_TIMER();` and `MINIMAL_SPEED_CRITICAL_CODE();`.  That's a problem because it adds time spent in the speed-critical section that doesn't need to exist.

I don't want to make the critical section itself any longer than it needs to be, so I'm hesitant to relax the optimization.  (the same action that causes this problem may also be what makes the final version fit inside the time available)  So how can I tell it that "this behavior" needs to stay pure and uncluttered, but still optimize it fully?

---

I've used inline assembly before, so I'm sure I could figure out again how to communicate between that and C without completely tying up or clobbering registers, etc.  But I'd much rather stick with 100% C if I can, and let the compiler figure out how not to run over itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the direct answer that I as looking for, but I found something that works.  So it's technically an XY problem, but I'll still take a direct answer to the question as stated.

---

Here's what I ended up doing:

### 1. Separate the speed-critical section into its own function, and prevent it from inlining:

```
void __attribute__((noinline)) _fast_function(uint8_t arg1, uint8_t arg2)
{
    //start speed-critical section
    SYNC_TO_TIMER();
    MINIMAL_SPEED_CRITICAL_CODE(arg1, arg2);
    //end speed-critical section
}

void normal_function(void)
{
    if (READY)
    {
        ACKNOWLEDGE();

        SETUP_PART1();
        SETUP_PART2();  //determines arg1, arg2

        _fast_function(arg1, arg2);

        CLEANUP();
    }
}
```

That keeps the speed-critical stuff together, and by itself.  It also adds some overhead, but that happens OUTSIDE the fast part, where I can afford it.

### 2. Manually unroll some loops:

The original code was something like this:

```
uint8_t data[3];

uint8_t byte_num = 3;
while(byte_num)
{
    byte_num--;

    uint8_t bit_mask = 0b10000000;
    while(bit_mask)
    {
        if(data[byte_num] & bit_mask)   WEIRD_OUTPUT_1();
        else                            WEIRD_OUTPUT_0();

        bit_mask >>= 1;
    }
}
```

The new code is like this:

```
#define WEIRD_OUTPUT(byte,bit)                  \
    do                                          \
    {                                           \
        if((byte) & (bit))  WEIRD_OUTPUT_1();   \
        else                WEIRD_OUTPUT_0();   \
    } while(0)

uint8_t data[3];

WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b10000000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b01000000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b00100000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b00010000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b00001000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b00000100);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b00000010);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b00000001);

WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b10000000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b01000000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b00100000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b00010000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b00001000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b00000100);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b00000010);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[1],0b00000001);

WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b10000000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b01000000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b00100000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b00010000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b00001000);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b00000100);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b00000010);
WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[0],0b00000001);
```

In addition to dropping the loop code itself, this also replaces an array index with a direct access, and a variable with a constant, each of which offers its own speedup.

And it still barely fits in the time available.  **But it does fit!**  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a memory barrier to prevent ordering code across it:

```
__asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
```

The compiler will not move volatile accesses or memory accesses across such a barrier.  It might however move other stuff across it like arithmetic that does not involve memory access.

If the compiler is reordering code, that it's a valid compilation w.r.t. the C language standard, which means that you'll have some hard time avoiding it by pure C code hacks.

If you are after speed, then consider writing `WEIRD_OUTPUT(data[2],0b10000000);` etc. as inline asm, or writing the whole function in assembly.  This gives you definite control over the timing (not considering IRQs), whereas the C language standard does not make any statements on program timing whatsoever.